# Missing MBean Type: javax.cache:type=CacheStatistics while using infinispan as 2LC in wildfly

Tags: hibernate, wildfly, infinispan, jcache, java-melody

We are using wildfly 18.0.1 as application server. As the hibernate-ehcache module is deprecated we changed to the hibernate-jcache module. Wildfly uses infinispan as jcache implementation by default.
We also use java melody to monitor our application. Melody found and displayed the ehcaches statisticts out of the box. But it does not find the infinispan statisticts.
The infinispan cache is configured in the standalone.xml:

```
...
<cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="entity" module="org.infinispan.hibernate-cache" statistics-enabled="true">
    <local-cache name="timestamps"/>
    <local-cache name="entity" statistics-enabled="true">
        <object-memory size="10000"/>
        <expiration lifespan="300000"/>
    </local-cache>
</cache-container>
...
```

persistence.xml

```
<persistence version="2.2"
             xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
                                 http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="entityManager">
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/...</jta-data-source>
        <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect"/>

            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.statistics" value="true" />
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

So the statistics is enabled. So following the [javadoc](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/javax.cache/cache-api/latest/javax/cache/CacheManager.html#enableStatistics-java.lang.String-boolean-) of the CacheManager the statistic objects must be registered with an ObjectName that is unique and has the following type and attributes:

Type: javax.cache:type=CacheStatistics

That does not happen. Java melody is looking for these objects and can not find any. So it cannot display any informations regarding the caches.

[image]

Screenshot of VisualVM showing the infinispan MBeans.

Just wondering if I oversee something or if this is something that should be handled by wildfly or infinispan?
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What do you see when you open the MBeans report in javamelody monitoring?

Comment: Not sure which information you need. Added screenshot of the statistic node of the MBeans.

Comment: You have more or less the same information as the VisualVM Mbeans screen in the page /monitoring?part=mbeans of javamelody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand everything correct, wildfly is using infinispan as default 2LC provider not as jcache provider. It uses module 'infinispan-hibernate' and not 'infinispan-jcache'. Thats' why it does not behave like a jcache-provider. It is not used that way.
@evernat comment configuring infinispan as jcache-provider leaded me to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the screenshot, infinispan has registered the MBeans under the object name `org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan:type=Cache` and not under the object name `javax.cache:type=CacheStatistics`.

So it's normal that javamelody does not find the javax.cache statistics.

Comment: Do you plan to extend javamelody to also search with the object name ´org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan:type=Cache´ for caches?

Comment: No, that's not the plan. The plan should be that infinispan allows to register javax cache statistics in JMX MBeans, because javax cache is now the standard api (JSR107) in JavaEE/JakartaEE.

Comment: To have javax.cache statistics with infinispan, you may want to use hibernate-jcache and infinispan-jcache dependencies, if not already in WildFly, and properties hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=jcache, hibernate.javax.cache.provider=?, hibernate.javax.cache.uri=? (I have not tried myself).
And enable javax cache statistics in infinispan if that exists of course.